# JavaScript combine original object with sub array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, object

I have an large array of objects with some keys:values, one of the keys has a value that is an array of objects. I want to reduce the subarray into a new array of objects.

I can't figure out a solution using mapping thus far.

```
const warehouse = [
    {
        Server: 'EU',
        Department: 'Paper',
        Suppliers: [
            {
                Name: 'EU Paper',
                Contract: 'Active'
            },
            {
                Name: 'Local Tree',
                Contract: 'Ended'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        Server: 'US',
        Department: 'Steel',
        Suppliers: [
            {
                Name: 'Steel Research',
                Contract: 'Active'
            },
            {
                Name: 'Heat Vantage',
                Contract: 'Active'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Output should be

```
const suppliers = [
    {
        Server: 'EU',
        Department: 'Paper',
        Name: 'EU Paper',
        Contract: 'Active'
    },
    {
        Server: 'EU',
        Department: 'Paper',
        Name: 'Local Tree',
        Contract: 'Ended'
    },
    {
        Server: 'US',
        Department: 'Steel',
        Name: 'Steel Research',
        Contract: 'Active'
    },
    {
        Server: 'US',
        Department: 'Steel',
        Name: 'Heat Vantage',
        Contract: 'Active'
    },
]
```

I can do this with basic JavaScript but i would like to see an option that optimizes for performance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` to loop thru the array and flat the result. Use `map` to loop thru the `Suppliers` array.

```js
const warehouse = [{"Server":"EU","Department":"Paper","Suppliers":[{"Name":"EU Paper","Contract":"Active"},{"Name":"Local Tree","Contract":"Ended"}]},{"Server":"US","Department":"Steel","Suppliers":[{"Name":"Steel Research","Contract":"Active"},{"Name":"Heat Vantage","Contract":"Active"}]}];

let result = warehouse.flatMap(({Suppliers,...r}) => Suppliers.map(o => ({ ...o,...r})));
console.log(result);
```

You can also use `concat` and `map`

```js
const warehouse = [{"Server":"EU","Department":"Paper","Suppliers":[{"Name":"EU Paper","Contract":"Active"},{"Name":"Local Tree","Contract":"Ended"}]},{"Server":"US","Department":"Steel","Suppliers":[{"Name":"Steel Research","Contract":"Active"},{"Name":"Heat Vantage","Contract":"Active"}]}];

let result = [].concat(...warehouse.map(({Suppliers,...r}) => Suppliers.map(o => ({ ...o,...r}))));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The second option works for me. I'm interested in the first one but .flatMap is not a method for me?

Comment: As per doc, `flatMap` is compatible with Nodejs 11.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap

Comment: ..Or you can use `Polyfill`